# In CSS, how can I fill the empty space of each line wrapped from a paragraph with dashes?

Tags: css

I've been trying to figure this out and can't find the answer. What I want to do is fill the empty space with dashes, but not on the last line only, I want to fill each line since I am not using justify for my text-align.

[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AipnX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you started working on this:

1. Calculate (or set) the number of characters per line and the number of total lines.
2. Fill up a container with dashes and place it behind the original text.
3. Put the original text in a span with white background to only show the dashes at the end of the line

Very quick write-up, feel free to improve:

```js
const lineHeight = 16;
const maxLength = 30;
const height = document.querySelector(".wrapper").scrollHeight
const fillup = document.querySelector(".fillup");
fillup.innerHTML = "-".repeat(height / lineHeight * maxLength);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Courier;
  max-width: 30ch;
  line-height: 16px;
}

span {
  background: white;
}

.fillup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  <div class="fillup"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is working perfectly, only when I am dealing with 10 of paragraphs, it is getting lack and when I have a <ol><li> with 30px indentation, the dashes still start from the left=0 not from the left=30px

Comment: @EddyHartono dont forget to set the background to white for every element you add to this example (or in case of the list, add a wrapper div with white background), otherwise the dashes will ofc show (they cover the whole background) - also you need to set line heights accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If transparency is not need you can play with gradients:

```css
p {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px;
  /* adjust the 20px and the 80% to control the dash */
  background: conic-gradient(at 80% 2px,#0000 75%,#000 0) 100% .5lh/20px 1lh;
  /* lh is a new unit if it doesn't work use the below 
   line-height: 1.2em;
   background: conic-gradient(at 80% 2px,#0000 75%,#000 0) 100% .6em/20px 1.2em;
   
   */
}
p span {
  background: #fff;
  padding-right: 10px;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At quod est quis modi, ab necessitatibus, ipsa alias cum consectetur, dolorum mollitia omnis cupiditate laboriosam debitis nisi? Laboriosam impedit voluptatibus minima. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At quod est quis modi, ab necessitatibus, ipsa alias cum consectetur, dolorum mollitia omnis cupiditate laboriosam debitis nisi? Laboriosam impedit voluptatibus minima.
    </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```html
<article>
  <p>
    <span>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At quod est quis modi, ab necessitatibus, ipsa alias cum consectetur, dolorum mollitia omnis cupiditate laboriosam debitis nisi? Laboriosam impedit voluptatibus minima. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. At quod est quis modi, ab necessitatibus, ipsa alias cum consectetur, dolorum mollitia omnis cupiditate laboriosam debitis nisi? Laboriosam impedit voluptatibus minima.
    </span>
  </p>
  <div>
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  </div>
</article>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
  font-family: monospace;
}

article {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
}

span {
  background-color: white;
}

div {
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; 
  text-align: justify;
}
```

[CodePen demo](https://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/LYgBxZy)